# How to manipulate dihedral angles in pre-optimized molecule coordinates?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I want to explore the low energy states of an amino acid or a peptide by generating input geometries, defined by multiple dihedral angles of the backbone or the side chain. From these starting conformations I want to do geometry optimization to yield local energy minimum geometries.
The following approaches failed:

- Using the *ModRedundant* keyword in the Gaussian09 package to define new values for the dihedral angles. This crashes for larger molecules and major changes in the coordinates.
- Detecting the substructure of the molecule (e.g. the backbone) by SMILE / SMARTS pattern and using *obrotate* from the openbabel package to change the values. Works fine for a single dihedral or maybe two, but afterwards these changes the pattern of the substructure is not necessarily detected anymore and no further dihedral angle can be changed.
- Usage of a well chosen Z-Matrix: The great disadvantage is, that I don't know how to yield a Z-Matrix with the wanted dihedrals from a given geometry and therefore I can't start from a pre-optimized structure.

Are there any other attempts to this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did this stuff by a self-made script for a long time (but had to prepare the input manually for every molecule).

Meanwhile, I came along [confab](https://code.google.com/p/confab/).

> Confab is an open source conformation generator whose goal is the systematic coverage of conformational space.

A detailed description how it works can be found in the authors [publication](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1758-2946-3-8).

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. Why don't you explain in a bit more detail the approach you ended up using (maybe even with code or pseudocode)? That way, your answer would be of help to other users with a similar problem (this is, after all, what StackExchange is for), and maybe someone even has an idea how to avoid some of that manual work.

Comment: In case you are not familiar with the StackExchange network: The downvote is a sign that the answer *in its current form* is not seen as helpful - it can (and will) be removed if the answer is edited appropriately. Self answers are perfectly fine (and even encouraged and likely to be upvoted), as long as they are a useful contribution to the site.